# pyqt5 opening third new window from second window

Tags: python, windows, api, pyqt5, designer

firstly i have created a object form `MainWindow` than i am trying to make another object with same
how i should close Third window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")       
        MainWindow.resize(548, 479)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(14)
.         ... 
    def users_window(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow() 
        ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self.window )
        self.window.show()
        MainWindow.hide()
    
     def admin_window(self):
        self.window1 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui1 = Ui_ThirdWindow()
        ui1.setupUi(self.window1)
        self.window1.show()
        MainWindow.hide()

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, SecondWindow ):
        SecondWindow.setObjectName("SecondWindow")
        SecondWindow.resize(588, 437)
        SecondWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:#c5d5cb;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        ...
class Ui_ThirdWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, ThirdWindow):
        ThirdWindow.setObjectName("ThirdWindow")
        ThirdWindow.resize(588, 437)
        ThirdWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:#c5d5cb;")
        ...


     def validating_admin(self):
        AdminID = self.AdminID.text()
        print(AdminID)
        Admin_password = self.Admin_password.text()
        print(type(Admin_password))
        validation = f"""
        select password from admin where adminID = {AdminID};"""
        result = database1.execute_query(None , validation)
        if (result == Admin_password) :
            print("Correct password")  
            self.window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            ui2 = Ui_Admin_main_page()
            ui2.setupUi(self.window2)
            self.window2.show()
            print(result)
            ThirdWindow.hide()   #here if ThirdWindow is not Hiding
        else :
            print("Wrong Password")
            QMessageBox.about( "Alert", "Wrong password or userID !!)
```

above here is my problem solve it

```
class Ui_Admin_main_page(object):
    def setupUi(self, Admin_main_page):
        Admin_main_page.setObjectName("Admin_main_page")
        Admin_main_page.resize(588, 437)
```

how i should hide ThirdWindow with running window2 at same time
ThirdWindow is not Hiding

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share a _minimal_ code snippet…